# AppleScript doesn't complete when parsing large json structure

Tags: python, json, applescript, macos-monterey

I have an iMac 2017 with Monterey 12.6.

I am forced to call my API in python to have a correct JSON structure for results.

For information, this is the URL that I call in python (coingecko limits the result to the 100 first results):

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?ids=acala,alpaca-finance,altair,astar,avalanche-2,baanx,bbeefy-finance,bifrost-native-coin,binancecoin,binance-eth,binance-usd,bitcoin,cardano,chainlink,chainx,chronicle,coin-capsule,colony,cosmos,crabada,crypto-com-chain,cumrocket,curve-dao-token,dappradar,dogecoin,elrond-erd-2,ergo,ethereum,evmos,exeedme,fantom,ftx-token,fuse-network-token,genshiro,green-satoshi-token,havven,hooked-protocol,integritee,kadena,karura,kintsugi,kucoin-shares,kusama,kuswap,matic-network,metagame-arena,metagods,metavault,mina-protocol,moonbeam,moonpot,moonriver,nafty,near,osmosis,pancakeswap-token,paraswap,platypus-finance,pluton,polkadot,safemoon,shiba-inu,kryll,kucoin-shares,kusama,kuswap,lido-dao,matic-network,maze-token,memepad,metagame-arena,metagods,metis-token,mina-protocol,moonbeam,moonpot,moonriver,movn,nafter,nafty,near,nexo,nftlaunch,orion-protocol,osmosis,paid-network,pancakeswap-token,paraswap,platypus-finance,polkadot,polkamon,polkamarkets,polkastarter,polycat-finance,polychain-monsters,polygonfarm-finance,presearch,safemoon,safepal,shiba-inu,shiden,solana,staked-ether,staked-olympus,stasis-eurs,stepn,sushi,swissborg,switch,tether,terrausd,the-graph,the-sandbox,unifarm,uniswap,usd-coin,valkyrie-protocol,wizarre-scroll,zelcash&vs_currency=EUR"
```

The result in Python is something like that but with many others cryptos:

```
[{'id': 'bitcoin', 'symbol': 'btc', 'name': 'Bitcoin', 'image': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579', 'current_price': 15765.21, 'market_cap': 303279048538, 'market_cap_rank': 1, 'fully_diluted_valuation': 330971307514, 'total_volume': 9519061248, 'high_24h': 15812.98, 'low_24h': 15758.06, 'price_change_24h': -18.11016048005331, 'price_change_percentage_24h': -0.11474, 'market_cap_change_24h': -207406972.0255127, 'market_cap_change_percentage_24h': -0.06834, 'circulating_supply': 19242937.0, 'total_supply': 21000000.0, 'max_supply': 21000000.0, 'ath': 59717, 'ath_change_percentage': -73.60052, 'ath_date': '2021-11-10T14:24:11.849Z', 'atl': 51.3, 'atl_change_percentage': 30631.82104, 'atl_date': '2013-07-05T00:00:00.000Z', 'roi': None, 'last_updated': '2022-12-25T14:21:15.974Z'}, {'id': 'ethereum', 'symbol': 'eth', 'name': 'Ethereum', 'image': 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/279/large/ethereum.png?1595348880', 'current_price': 1142.38, 'market_cap': 137652680087, 'market_cap_rank': 2, 'fully_diluted_valuation': 137652680087, 'total_volume': 2165257956, 'high_24h': 1149.42, 'low_24h': 1141.8, 'price_change_24h': -1.0190823115187868, 'price_change_percentage_24h': -0.08913, 'market_cap_change_24h': -73228021.97866821, 'market_cap_change_percentage_24h': -0.05317, 'circulating_supply': 120523982.078808, 'total_supply': 120523982.078808, 'max_supply': None, 'ath': 4228.93, 'ath_change_percentage': -72.99273, 'ath_date': '2021-12-01T08:38:24.623Z', 'atl': 0.381455, 'atl_change_percentage': 299310.75605, 'atl_date': '2015-10-20T00:00:00.000Z', 'roi': {'times': 95.89474372830291, 'currency': 'btc', 'percentage': 9589.474372830291}, 'last_updated': '2022-12-25T14:20:55.699Z'}]
```

Content of my AppleScript:

```
set desktop_folder to "$HOME/PycharmProjects/crypto/"
set valReturned to do shell script "python3 " & desktop_folder & "crypto.py"

set coins to (every item in valReturned) as list
repeat with n from 1 to count of coins
    set coin to item n of coins
end repeat
```

The AppleScript process uses 99% of my processor.

If I comment on the loop part, I have a huge JSON (it's just the result for 100 different cryptocurrencies). I can't post it because when I copy-paste its contents, it exceeds 81,000 characters here.

Why does this crash AppleScript?

I've already posted on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74842323/apple-script-crashes-when-making-a-curl-call-while-curl-is-working-in-command-pr?noredirect=1#comment132083132_74842323) but I didn't do it the same way.
I think I could decrease the number of cryptos in my request but it's still strange that it crashes this way. I have no problem with Excel and powerquery for example.

I feel like the best way to produce a Numbers file would be to generate a CSV and then use AppleScript to import that CSV into Numbers and then apply formatting. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is in the Python script? If it only gets the JSON string, all your AppleScript will be doing is stepping through the (81,000+) characters of that string, which is going to take a little time.  What _exactly_ are you wanting to do?

Comment: The goal is to generate a Numbers file containing the values ​​I previously parsed. Since I'd like to add some formatting in Number as well, I thought it best to do it via AppleScript. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can only speculate, as I don't have/use any Apple-anything:

- There's no linebreaks in the JSON. If loading/processing it with a tool/language that relies (internally) on strings, it may exceed a maximum character limit for a string
- In both cases, your `valReturned` is a variable in AppleScript. It may come with some size limitations, and also you're filling/setting it via the textual characters that come from the output of `echo` or `pyhton3`. This can lead to delays and size limitations (crashes?). Especially with `echo`, printing text on the terminal is often limited by the terminal's output/drawing/rendering speed, not how fast the computer can process the characters.
- Not sure how AppleScript handles JSON - does it parse the JSON and keep it all in memory? Also, does it try to be clever and unserialize/demarshal the JSON into its own data types, creating many objects etc. for later programmatic access? You seem to then also have two copies of it, one in a list structure in `coins` and then the `valReturned` (as a string I assume).
- Potentially more similar reasons like that...

If you're already able to call `echo` and `python3`, maybe you do not need to use AppleScript to iterate over the JSON entries? As you seem to be able to write the JSON from the network into a file directly, maybe you do not need to have the AppleScript load/keep the JSON data? Wonder if trying to avoid AppleScript's exposure to the JSON or results/output from the external programs would mitigate the performance + crash problems.

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript will perform the shell script without any issues, but note that the results will be a *string*.  Your sample script is just going through the (81,000+) characters of that string, which takes a little time.  Many languages (such as Python) provide direct support for JSON strings - for AppleScript, Cocoa (via AppleScriptObjC) can be used.

The JSON string from the shell script can be parsed to get a list of records (the result can also be left as Cocoa objects for use with those methods).  The individual list items can then stepped through using a repeat statement and the various record key values used as desired, for example:

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set theURL to "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?ids=acala,alpaca-finance,altair,astar,avalanche-2,baanx,bbeefy-finance,bifrost-native-coin,binancecoin,binance-eth,binance-usd,bitcoin,cardano,chainlink,chainx,chronicle,coin-capsule,colony,cosmos,crabada,crypto-com-chain,cumrocket,curve-dao-token,dappradar,dogecoin,elrond-erd-2,ergo,ethereum,evmos,exeedme,fantom,ftx-token,fuse-network-token,genshiro,green-satoshi-token,havven,hooked-protocol,integritee,kadena,karura,kintsugi,kucoin-shares,kusama,kuswap,matic-network,metagame-arena,metagods,metavault,mina-protocol,moonbeam,moonpot,moonriver,nafty,near,osmosis,pancakeswap-token,paraswap,platypus-finance,pluton,polkadot,safemoon,shiba-inu,kryll,kucoin-shares,kusama,kuswap,lido-dao,matic-network,maze-token,memepad,metagame-arena,metagods,metis-token,mina-protocol,moonbeam,moonpot,moonriver,movn,nafter,nafty,near,nexo,nftlaunch,orion-protocol,osmosis,paid-network,pancakeswap-token,paraswap,platypus-finance,polkadot,polkamon,polkamarkets,polkastarter,polycat-finance,polychain-monsters,polygonfarm-finance,presearch,safemoon,safepal,shiba-inu,shiden,solana,staked-ether,staked-olympus,stasis-eurs,stepn,sushi,swissborg,switch,tether,terrausd,the-graph,the-sandbox,unifarm,uniswap,usd-coin,valkyrie-protocol,wizarre-scroll,zelcash&vs_currency=EUR"

set valReturned to (do shell script "/usr/bin/curl " & quoted form of theURL) -- string
set theResult to parseJSON from valReturned -- list of records

set output to "Current Prices:" & return -- header for the example
repeat with anItem in theResult -- the individual list items
   -- do whatever with the record key values
   set theName to |name| of anItem -- "name" is a keyword
   set theValue to current_price of anItem
   set output to output & theName & ": " & theValue & return
end repeat
return output

# Parse a JSON string into a data structure.
to parseJSON from sourceString given coercion:coerce : true
   if class of sourceString is not in {string} then error "parseJSON error: source is not a string"
   set theString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:sourceString
   set theData to theString's dataUsingEncoding:(current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding)
   set {theObject, theError} to current application's NSJSONSerialization's JSONObjectWithData:theData options:0 |error|:(reference)
   if theObject is missing value then error "parseJSON error: " & (theError's userInfo's objectForKey:"NSDebugDescription")
   if coerce then if (theObject's isKindOfClass:(current application's NSArray)) as boolean then
      return theObject as list
   else
      return theObject as record
   end if
   return theObject -- leave as NSArray or NSDictionary
end parseJSON
```